# Cannot read property 'sapUiGlobalLogo' of undefined and Cannot read property 'sapUshellLeftViewPortWidthMedium' of undefined

Tags: sapui5

I am using onPremise Fiori Launchpad.I have followed below blog for customizing Fiori Launchpad.

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/19/colorful-fiori-part-3-sea-blue/

I have used the theme designer to edit the logo.I have uploaded the logo in Quick View.

Theme and logo is working fine in Dev system but its showing error after moving to Testing system.
The below error occurs while moving from Dev System to Testing system

[Cannot read property 'sapUiGlobalLogo' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5w6z.png)

[Cannot read Property 'sapUshellLeftViewPortWidthMedium' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4D8x.jpg)

Comment: did you forget anything during transport to test? The error tells you that probably shell or fiori launchpad cannot be identified in test-environment (while in dev it works) - because it tries to call a method from an object which was not found (undefined).. while in dev this object is found. this leads to the question of the system differences.

Comment: I am transporting theme using tcode /ui5/theme_tool.Is this theme contains image that I am using in Quick View? Because I didn't transport logo image separately.and If I need to transport image separately then how will I transport?

Comment: Did you invalidate the cache in test system with transaction /ui5/theme_tool after import?

Comment: I forgot to import parameter of sap-theme..now it is working fine in testing system..thank you so much